# Python can't use setter

Tags: python, oop, decorator

here is my issue, when i'm using @property decorator I can't use setter

```
class Worker:

def __init__(self,name):
    self.__name = name

@property
def name(self):
    return self.__name

@name.setter
def set_name(self,new_name):
    self.__name = new_name

worker1 = Worker('A')
print(worker1.name)
worker1.name = 'B'
print(worker1.name)
```

It gives AttributeError: can't set attribute 'name', when I use setter

Comment: With this indentation, the code does not make sense to me. Please [edit] the question and adjust the code until the preview shows the code as you have it.

Comment: Rename `set_name` to `name`.

Comment: Because decorators assign their return value to the name of the function they are decorating, you *must* use the same name as the property. `name.setter` returns a *new* property that you want to replace the old, setter-less, property.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of underscores! The double `__name` asks for name mangling, something you probably don't want here. Better to stick with single `_name`, indicating "private, keep out!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rewrite this without decorator syntax.

```
class Worker:

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.__name = name
    
    def name(self):
        return self.__name
    name = proprety(name)
    
    def set_name(self,new_name):
        self.__name = new_name

    set_name = name.setter(set_name)
```

This makes it easier to see that you now have *two* similar properties: `name`, which only provides read-only access to the `__name` attribute, and `set_name`, which has a getter *and* a setter for the same attribute. `name.setter` takes a method, and returns a new property that replaces the old setter (if any) of `name` with the given function.

You want a *single* property named `name`, so you must use the same name when defining the setter.

```
class Worker:

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.__name = name
    
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name
    name = proprety(name)
    
    @name.setter
    def name(self,new_name):
        self.__name = new_name
```

The decorators are a way to simplify code like the following:

```
class Worker:

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.__name = name
    
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name
    
    def set_name(self,new_name):
        self.__name = new_name

    name = property(get_name, set_name)
    del get_name, set_name
```

Comment: thank you so much, for such beautiful explanation

Answer (score 0):

Change `set_name` to `name`.

[Python docs for @property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

> Be sure to give the additional functions the same name as the original property (x in this case.)